# My data in popular web apps like Facebook, YouTube

Tags: privacy

Why do these companies allow to download your data? 
Is there some law enforcing them to do so?
How complete should these data be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a purely legal question. Try [law.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

GDPR, article 15, enforces the [right of access by the data subject](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-15-gdpr/). This means a company must be able to check, which personal data is stored, and it must also provide a full copy on request. Failure to do so can result in significant fines.

All the relevant requirements and limitations regarding the right of access are listed in the link I provided above.